# Can I redirect after successful validation with form_for :remote => true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need advice for a form with :remote => true.

I need "remote => true" to show validation errors without reloading the page (because my form is in an overlay).

- Is it possible to redirect to another page after successfull
  validation?
- If not, is it possible to use a
  normal form (without 'remote true')
  but to have validation errors appear
  without page refresh? Maybe I should
  use javascript validation.

I'm using rails3 and jquery ujs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a redirect by javascript.

Add in your js view render in success this code by example :

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
```

You can replace the url by a named_route or url_for call.

Comment: see the push_state so explain on railscast : http://railscasts.com/episodes/246-ajax-history-state

Comment: Thanks. I was also thinking about the same.